# WordPress Admin Doesnt work

Tags: admin, errors

I was working on the WP admin about an hour ago, all good. I was able to browse to difference pages. I didn't log off. Now, when I try to go to the /wp-admin/ page I get blank white. I navigate to the log files and this is whats on the bottom lines.

> [16-Mar-2020 15:20:30 America/Boise] 
>    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>    get_header() in /home3/tcokchal/public_html/launch/index.php:18 Stack
>    trace:
>    # 0 {main}   thrown in /home3/tcokchal/public_html/launch/index.php on line 18

Comment: You say you were working, but what exactly were you doing? get_header is an essential part of themes so I guess you were modifying a template? Perhaps try and restore that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing a file from the WP 'core'.

Make a backup copy of your wp-settings.php file, then upload a freshly-downloaded copy of WordPress. Don't upload the wp-settings.php file - that contains your database configuration.

Your plugins and themes will still be there, as will your database.